# Таблица из div на css

Tags: css, html, height

Всем привет.

Есть вложенный словарь `all_networks`, например:

```
[[IPv4Network(u'10.224.0.0/17'), IPv4Network(u'10.224.128.0/17')], 
[IPv4Network(u'10.224.0.0/18'), IPv4Network(u'10.224.64.0/18'), IPv4Network(u'10.224.128.0/18'), IPv4Network(u'10.224.192.0/18')], 
[IPv4Network(u'10.224.0.0/19'), IPv4Network(u'10.224.32.0/19'), IPv4Network(u'10.224.64.0/19'), IPv4Network(u'10.224.96.0/19'), IPv4Network(u'10.224.128.0/19'), IPv4Network(u'10.224.160.0/19'), IPv4Network(u'10.224.192.0/19'), IPv4Network(u'10.224.224.0/19')],
```

из которого во view я делаю таблицу из div'ов.

```
{% for colmn in all_networks %}
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; display: inline-block; " >
        {%for cell in colmn %}
            <div style="border: 1px solid red; height:auto ;" >{{cell}}</div>
        {% endfor%}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Мне необходимо чтобы div'ы растягивались по высоте всей страницы, т.е. если смотреть на изображение в аттаче, слева текущая ситуация, справа целевая схема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Коллеги, у кого какие варианты, как можно добиться желаемого эффекта?

Comment: а код - где минимально самодостаточный код для воспроизведения проблемного участка ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый день!

Вам подойдет css-селектор [align-items: stretch](https://webref.ru/css/align-items).

Для того, чтобы все заработало как хотите вы, вам потребуется к родительскому элементу применить `display: flex`. Почитайте подробнее о [flexbox](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/), если ещё не работали с этим свойством.

Comment: спасибо, то что надо!

Comment: @Surf, обратите внимание на префиксы к флексу. Это увеличит совместимость с разными браузерами. На данный момент флекс корректно без префиксов отображается на 96% устройств, а с префиксами на 98%.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно сопровождать такую таблицу надо уметь ....

Первый пример не адаптивный 
Второй пример чуть чуть адаптивен

```css
.table {
  width: 900px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.table-cell:first-child div {
  height: 50%;
}

.table-cell:nth-child(2) div {
  height: 25%;
}

.table-cell:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.table-cell:nth-child(3) {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-cell div {
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Даже чуть чуть её адаптировал топорным методом :

```css
.table {
  width: 900px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
}

.item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.table-cell:first-child div {
  height: 50%;
}

.table-cell:nth-child(2) div {
  height: 25%;
}

.table-cell:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.table-cell:nth-child(3) {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-cell div {
  padding: 12px;
}

@media (max-width:1024px) {
  .table {
    width: 800px;
    transform: scale(.8);
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .table {
    transform: scale(.9);
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
      <div class="item">lorem</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```